# Evaluating the surface Integral of a solid enclosed by a cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

Evaluate $\iint_S (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dS$ where $S$ is the boundary of the solid enclosed by the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $z = 4$.
I tried to solve this by:

$$\iint_S (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)dS = \iint_{S_1} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)dS +  \iint_{S_2} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dS$$

where $S_1$ is the surface around the cone, and $S_2$ is the intersection of the cone and $z = 4$.

So for $S_1$ I have:
$$ r(x,y) = \left\langle x,y, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right\rangle $$
$$ r_x = \left\langle 1,0, \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right\rangle $$
$$ r_y = \left\langle 0,1, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right\rangle $$

So, the cross product of $r_x$ and $r_y$ is:

$$ r_x \times r_y = \left\langle \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, 1 \right\rangle $$
and the magnitude of that is: $\sqrt2 $

So,

$$\iint_{S_1} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)dS = \iint_{D} (x^2 + y^2 + x^2 + y^2) \sqrt2 \,dS $$ which I've calculated to be $256\pi\sqrt2$

Now I'm trying to calculate $\iint_{S_2} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dS$ and I'm extremely confused on how to parametrize it. I know that the surface is $z = 4$ with $x^2 + y^2 \le 16 $ But how would I parameterize it? Would I use the same parameterization as the previous step?

I'd appreciate any help with this, but please explain!

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: Please parametrize the surface $x^2+y^2 \leq 16, z = 4$ as 

$(r \cos \theta, r\sin\theta, 4), 0 \leq r \leq 4, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Your integrand becomes $16+r^2$

Comment: Thank you! I parametrized it this way and it was much nicer to solve. My answer for the last part is 384 pi. Does my first part look right? Or should I have been using the opposite orientation and my value should have been -256π sqrt(2)?

Comment: Your answer for the first part is correct. When you are integrating a scalar field, orientation is not relevant. Did you go through the link I sent in response to another question of yours.

Comment: Yes, but we're not supposed to use that shorthand formula yet. This is supposed to help us practice without that shorthand formula first. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Your answer for the second part is correct as well.